# SQL query to get dif between dates in select statment

Tags: sql

I have a two tables call RFS and RFS_History.

```
 RFS_id  | name 
 --------+--------
    12   |  xx
    14   |  yy
    15   |  zz
```

figure 1 :RFS table

```
     RFS_id  |  gate | End    | start 
     --------+-------+--------+-------
        12   |  aa   | 19/02  | 20/03
        12   |  bb   | 30/01  | 12/08
        12   |  cc   | 30/01  | 12/08
        13   |  aa   | 30/01  | 12/08
        12   |  dd   | 30/01  | 12/08
```

figure 2 :RFS history

My initial query is a select * query to get information where FRSname ='xx'

```
SELECT * FROM RFS, RFSHistory 
WHERE RFSname="xx"  And RFShistory.RFS_ID=RFS.RFS_ID
```

result is:

```
     RFS_id  |  gate | End    | start 
     --------+-------+--------+-------
        12   |  aa   | 19/02  | 19/01
        12   |  bb   | 12/04  | 12/02
        12   |  cc   | 20/03  | 12/03
        12   |  dd   | 30/09  | 12/08
```

figure 3

however I want to get a result like bellow format :

```
 RFS_id  | gate_aa | gate_bb | gate_cc | gate_dd
 ----------------------------------------------
    12   | 30 days  |  60dyas | 8days   | 18days
```

`gate_aa` is duraion and it gets from `start - end date`. Please help me to write single query to get this result.

Comment: What RDMS are you using (oracle,mssql,mysql etc) ? What is the datatype of the end and start?

Answer (score 0):

Use `datediff()` to get date difference and `Pivot()` to convert row into cloumn 
like here in your case gate wise column

Sample Syntax

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query for get the difference b/w dates

> SELECT RFS.ID,(RFS_HISTORY.end_t-RFS_HISTORY.start_t) AS DiffDate,gate FROM RFS, RFS_HISTORY 
>   WHERE name='aa' And RFS_HISTORY.ID=RFS.ID group by RFS.ID,gate,RFS_HISTORY.end_t,RFS_HISTORY.start_t

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert rows into columns on the values. This can be done with the help of pivoting.

```
SELECT * FROM RFS, RFSHistory
pivot  for columname on [values]
```

I actually forgot the syntax but you can **google** it